# Clustering related areas with k-means

Tags: data-mining, clustering, text-mining

I am trying to cluster related areas of knowledge based in publications.For example a researcher has 3 keywords in a paper, in another paper he has 5 keywords, but 3 keywords are the same in the both papers. Then these 3 keywords are similar and It could be an area of knowledge. A sample of my file is:

```
'Domain Ontology,Semantic Web'
'Linked Data,Domain Ontology,Use Case'
'Domain Ontology,Linked Data,Semantic Annotation'
'GIS,Open GIS,Integrated Geo Systems'
'Open GIS,GIS'
```

My file contains 48963 rows and 19000 keywords. I have tried grouping words (like in the sample), using StringToWordVector (STWV), but I don't have good results. So I tried different K for my cluster since 3 until 13000. When K is greater my log likelihood decrease. In many models my words are grouped perfectly, but the percentages are not really good for some clusters. For example for K=3000, the 2999 have between 0,1% and 1% of the data, but the 3000 have the 21%. I am using WEKA. Anyone know some work related, some advice or any help is helpful...

Cheers.

Comment: These results sound typical for me, with k-means on text. Text is not what k-means was designed for, and cosine is okay for text search, but it doesn't *quantiy* similarity in a reliable way.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse So then Is there another reliable way to build my cluster? Or How do I estimate my true K?

Comment: There probably *is* no true k. And don't expect clustering to be *reliable*: it is an *explorative* approach, not an automatic.

Comment: Yes your right! But I'm using a bag of words, so at least I could cluster similar words based in the concurrency of different papers. For example:
`Domain Ontology GIS Integrated Geo Systems Linked Data Open GIS Semantic Annotation Semantic Web Use Case Cluster
1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 cluster1
1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 cluster1
1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 cluster1
0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 cluster0
0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 cluster0`

Am I wrong?

Comment: Good luck. Language when you only see bits and bytes is far from easy. I doubt 10% of your cluster assignments will be useable.

Comment: Ok. Thank you so much. @Anony-Mousse Then I won't waste time trying to do by this way. I'll start searching about LSI.

Comment: What you need is a *background knowledge database*. I don't think LSI etc. will be helpful here either. Because they cannot make the association "GIS, probably something with Geo" that a human would make just from the five examples you gave above. None of the standard algorithms can do that.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think k-means is the correct approach to this problem. You should look at doing topic modelling using latent semantic indexing.

Comment: I read something about clustering by using latent semantic indexing, but I don't really get it! Do you know some resources to theoretical o practical? Sorry I'm new in DM and TM I'm still learning.

Comment: No need to apologise, the best part of data analytics is that it's a continual learning process. The following link should provide a good intro >> [http://fastml.com/dimensionality-reduction-for-sparse-binary-data/]. Also try typing it in on Youtube to see what kind of video resources are available.